# Portico RTI + Java WEB Application = NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: simulation

I'm trying to start a Federate (HLA RTI) from a Java Web application, but I'm receiving the error **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hla/rti1516/FederateAmbassador.**

The same Federate is starting well from an ordinary java application.

My goal is to start the RTI and a Federation by starting a Federate when the web application is started. So I create a WebListener class to start my Federate:

```
@WebListener
public class Startup implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        //
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        Federate fed = new Federate();
        fed.start();
    }

}
```

This is the Federate start() code. I'll not put all code because this is not even reached:

```
public class Federate {

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("start");
        try {
            RTIambassador rtiAmb = RtiFactoryFactory.getRtiFactory().getRtiAmbassador();
            MyFederateAmbassador fedAmb = new MyFederateAmbassador();
...
}
```

When my webserver is starting, I never see the System.out.println("start") output, just only this error :

```
Grave: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class cmabreu.scorpio.startup.Startup
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hla/rti1516/FederateAmbassador
    at cmabreu.scorpio.startup.Startup.contextInitialized(Startup.java:29)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
```

My portico.jar is configured in Build Path and the Federate imports are pretty fine ( no errors ):

```
import hla.rti1516.AttributeHandle;
import hla.rti1516.AttributeHandleSet;
import hla.rti1516.AttributeHandleValueMap;
import hla.rti1516.LogicalTime;
import hla.rti1516.ObjectClassHandle;
import hla.rti1516.ObjectInstanceHandle;
import hla.rti1516.RTIambassador;
import hla.rti1516.ResignAction;
import hla.rti1516.jlc.RtiFactoryFactory;
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Earned the Tumbleweed badge for this question!! Eheh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contact Portico creator, Tim Pokorny, I solved the problem changing some code in Portico source. The Portico's Log4j is in conflict with catalina's Log4J and a few other things more.